# Why is Get-DnsClientServerAddress | select AddressFamily output not IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: powershell

When I type the cmdlet `Get-DnsClientServerAddress` I get all the interfaces my PC has like for example

```
InterfaceAlias               Interface Address ServerAddresses
                             Index     Family
--------------               --------- ------- ---------------
Ethernet                             7 IPv4    {10.10.15.40, 10.10.25.44}
```

So when I  type in `Get-DnsClientServerAddress | where AddressFamily -Like "4"` I would expect to see the Ethernet Adapter.

But for any reason it didn't show up. So I typed `Get-DnsClientServerAddress | select AddressFamily` and what I got was

```
AddressFamily
-------------
            2
           23
            2
           23
```

Can anyone explain this to me ?

Comment: This had me stumped for a little bit, looks like PowerShell is automatically formatting this. Check this link out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.addressfamily?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I understand now where those numbers come from. But quite confusing why it translates like this or either displays it "right" in first place but for "filtering" it translates the other. Quite unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you found, the `AddressFamily` is categorised internally using a (not obvious) numbering scheme, where IPv4 addresses are type '2'.  This comes from the underlying WMI type ([MSFT_DNSClientServerAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/dnsclientcimprov/msft-dnsclientserveraddress)) and is not an issue with PowerShell.

The default display helps you out by translating this to `IPv4`, etc, but you can't filter on that as it's for display only.  You can, however, still filter if you use the correct value:

```
Get-DnsClientServerAddress | Where-Object AddressFamily -Like 2
```

This formatting of data for display purposes happens all the time in PowerShell and is acheived through [Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6) files.  For example, compare the output of the Working Set values from `Get-Process` in table and list format:

```
PS C:\> Get-Process powershell 

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    662      31    97928     110256       1.27  11452   2 powershell



PS C:\> Get-Process powershell | Format-List *

Handles                    : 705
VM                         : 2204040044544
WS                         : 113082368
PM                         : 100356096
NPM                        : 31512
```

The property (itself added by PowerShell for convenience) is called `WS`, but is shown as `WS(K)` in the table and the actual value is stored in bytes, but is displayed in KB, so some manipulation is going on for the default output.

Comment: This is like quite hard then if you don't know it in first place when you want to automate something... like i wanted to make a script where it sets the settings for an adapter but frist I have to filter for it and this got me quite confused when it appeard first time

Comment: @kevin.  If you're new to some type in PowerShell it is helpful to use `Format-List` as shown above in order to see the 'raw' property names and values.  Also, [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-6) can be helpful in showing the methods (if any) and the underlying .NET type, which you can then research online.

Answer (score 1):

Following from my comment, I would use [Get-NetIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress?view=win10-ps) instead.

```
Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" | Select-Object FamilyAddress
```